# Unable to add Sass in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have created a blank project in angular 4 and I am trying to design it but the sass isn't working when ever I add sass and run project I am getting this error

```
body{
    h1{
        color : red;
    }
}
    ^
      Invalid CSS after "body{": expected "}", was "{"
      in C:projectname/src\styles.sass (line 1, column 6)
```

My index.html code is

```
<body>
  <h1>Here</h1>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message (C:projectname/src\styles.sass) It seems you're using the `.sass` extension for a `SCSS` file. Change your file name to `styles.scss`.

`Sass` and `SCSS` use two different and incompatible syntaxes.

> There are two syntaxes available for Sass. The first, known as **SCSS**
>   (Sassy CSS) and used throughout this reference, is an extension of the
>   syntax of CSS. This means that every valid CSS stylesheet is a valid
>   SCSS file with the same meaning. This syntax is enhanced with the Sass
>   features described below. Files using this syntax have the .scss
>   extension.
>
> The second and **older syntax**, known as the indented syntax (or
>   sometimes just “Sass”), provides a more concise way of writing CSS. It
>   uses indentation rather than brackets to indicate nesting of
>   selectors, and newlines rather than semicolons to separate properties.
>   Files using this syntax have the .sass extension.

Comment: @theCoder, Happy to help :)